# Python - replace words in .txt file that contain '-' and are less than 4 characters

Tags: python, regex, text, replace, hyphenation

I have a .txt file than I read with python. I want to replace all words that contain a dash '-' and are less then 4 characters with a whitespace. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have this for now:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

filedata = filedata.replace('bla', '')

with open('new text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Do some research into `str.replace()` and `len()`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, please share. NB: there should be an indent under `with`.

Comment: booo put in effort

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Checking string contents and word length are covered well in the documentation, tutorials, and other questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The program below should do the job

```
a = open("Location of the file",'r')
b= a.read()
a.close()
c = b.split()
str = ""
for i in c:

    if (((i.find('-')) != -1) and len(i)<4 ):
        pass
    else:
        str = str+i+" "
print(str)
a = open("Location of the file",'w')
a.write(str)
a.close()
```